# Reference for $q^{\eta\sum_{i}t_{\lambda_{i}}\otimes t_{\mu_{i}}}$ part of an expression for universal $R$-matrix of a quantum group algebra

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group) for quantum groups states that a quantum group $U_{q}\left(\mathfrak{g}\right)$ has an infinite formal sum that plays the role of an $R$ matrix, which is the product of two factors,

$$
q^{\eta\sum_{i}t_{\lambda_{i}}\otimes t_{\mu_{i}}}
$$

and an infinite formal such, where $\lambda_j$ is a basis for the dual space to the Cartan subalgebra, $\mu_j$ is the dual basis, $\eta=\pm1$, and $t_\lambda$ are the Cartan generators.

I find this expression to be convenient and useful, but I have searched the Wikipedia page's references and numerous other material on quantum group algebras, and did not find anything sufficiently similar.

I would appreciate a reference for the $q^{\eta\sum_{i}t_{\lambda_{i}}\otimes t_{\mu_{i}}}$ expression.